# Node JS for NOT asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've build my first Node application. It receives a list of offers and then I have to receive prices for each item on that offer.

Now the issue is I'm using `for` to go through the offers object like so

```
for(var k = 0; k < offers_object.length; k++){
   offer = offers_object[k];
   logger.info('Time Loaded is '+Math.floor(new Date() / 1000));
   ....
   some stuff...
   ....
   logger.info('Time request is '+Math.floor(new Date() / 1000));
   ....
   send request
   ....
   some more stuff after the requst
}
```

Now the problem is that whatever needs to be done inside the for loop seems to not be running synchronous. I'm using an API to request item prices which limits me by 8 requests per second.

And what I'm getting from the timers is:

```
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time Loaded is 1448409307
info: Time request is 1448409308
info: Time request is 1448409308
info: Time request is 1448409308
info: Time request is 1448409308
info: Time request is 1448409308
info: Time request is 1448409308
info: Time request is 1448409309
```

Comment: the `...some stuff...`'s are important.  Can you fill them in?

Comment: Just clarifying the item prices you are requesting from the API are being stored in the `offers_object` correct?

Comment: Hey, almost certain that the Math.floor() and division by 1000 will knock off the difference. Try printing the actual time, down to ms?

Comment: Umm...it's pretty simple. `logger.info('Time request is '+Math.floor(new Date() / 1000));` is in a callback which gets executed later. The for loop is forced to complete. So the callbacks can never run until the loop finishes.

Comment: i've pasted it here
EDIT: updated -removed comments section
http://codetidy.com/7382/

Comment: Tried using `forEach` but got the same results

Comment: There's a lot of asynchronous calls there.  The method of looping has no effect on that.  Async is important, or your performance will suffer horribly.

Comment: @TbWill4321 how would you suggest to overcome the 8 requests per sec ?

Comment: This question can't be answered generically.  We need to see the actual async code in order to suggest how best to handle things.  And, we need to see exactly what you're trying to rate limit.  So far, you've shown the least important parts of the code, not the ones that really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, you need to query an API only 8 times per second. To achieve this, you can loop on your items and use setTimeout to make a request each 1/8th of second :

```
var delay = 1000 / 8;
objects.forEach(function(val, index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        doSomething(index, val);
    }, index * delay);
});
```

Staying asynchronous is **very important** for performance and reactivity. It should not prevent you from doing anything.

Comment: You sir are genius!! Just one more thing, why should i pass the index to the function if i'm passing the whole object to it ?

Comment: You don't have to, I'm just illustrating that you can.